# Is there a solid definition for error 2007 in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Adobe's runtIme error documentation doesn't specify error code 2007 yet it gets raised here and there from time to time for different reasons.  The commonality among them seems to be when an API is specifically rejecting a parameter due to it being null.  This is opposed to trying to access a null reference.  My guess is that this is similar to an InvalidArgumentException in Java, but nothing I come across confirms that.

Anyone with knowledge at this depth?

Answer (score 0):

**ActionScript Error #2007**: Parameter text must be non-null.

You are probably trying to assing a **null** to the **text property** of a TextField :

```
var txtField:TextField = new TextField();

txtField.text = null;
```

This error is thrown by the **set text** function of [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#text) which expects a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This error is thrown by many different components, not just DisplayObject.  The error text is always different depending on the type of component that threw the error.  It seems logical to conclude that it's an arbitrary error code to explIcItly state "parameter cannot be null".  From what I understand, this helps disambiguate between attempting to access a null reference and passing a null reference to an API.